# how to get the exact latest response to HTML using observable in angular12

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, observable

I am using Angular12, and here i am using autocomplete in angular material, here the issue is that i am able to get result based on api hit, but in html, i always get latest-1 response shown.

Ts:

```
  private getAutoPopulateData(serchVal: any): Observable<string[]> {
    let data: any = [];
    let results: any = [];
    if (serchVal && serchVal.length > 0) {
      this.searchService.searchOpenSearchData(serchVal).subscribe((searchData: AutoPopulate) => {
        results = searchData.hits;
        if (results.hits.length > 0) {
          results.hits.forEach(h=>{
            let item=h._source;
             let addressProps=Object.keys(item).filter(p=> p.startsWith('AddressLine') && item[p].length >0);
             addressProps.forEach(ap=>{
                let addresses=item[ap].map((ai,idx)=>{
                 let address= `${ai} ${item.City[idx]} ${item.State} ${item.Zip[idx]}`;
                 return {name:item.ProfileName,address}
                });
               data= data.concat(addresses);
               this.seeResultsData = data.length;
             })
            });
        }
        this.resultData = of(data);
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
    }
    else {
      this.isLoading = false
    }
    if(this.resultData) {
      return this.resultData;
    } else 
    return null
  }

  private autoCompleteFormInit() {
    this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(500),
      tap((() => this.isLoading = true)),
      map(value => (this.getAutoPopulateData(value))
        .pipe(finalize(() => this.isLoading = false)))
    ).subscribe(value => {
    this.filteredOptions = value
    });
  }

public resultData: Observable<any> = of([]);
filteredOptions: Observable<any> = of([]);
searchOpenSearchData(searchValue:any): Observable<AutoPopulate> {
     let url =  URLConstants.openSearchUrl + searchValue;
     return this.http.get<AutoPopulate>(url);
   }
```

HTML:

```
 <input matInput aria-label="State" placeholder="Enter a Name" [matAutocomplete]="auto" class="paddingleft-5 text-medium" (ngModelChange)="updatedVal($event)" type="text" [formControl]="stateCtrl" *ngIf="form.value.tradingPartnerValue && dropdownSelection == 'tradingPartnerName'"/>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onOptionSelected($event.option)">
          <div *ngIf="showAutocomplete" class="{{seeResultsData >3 ? 'set-height' : ''}}">
            <mat-option *ngIf="isLoading" class="is-loading content-center">
              <mat-spinner diameter="50" class="show-center"></mat-spinner>
            </mat-option>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
            <mat-option class="option-custom text-medium" *ngFor="let state of filteredOptions | async"
              [value]="state" [ngClass]="{'hide-autocomplete': !showAutocomplete}">
                <span [innerHTML]="state.name | highlight : stateCtrl.value"></span>
                <span [innerHTML]="state.address | highlight : stateCtrl.value"></span>
            </mat-option>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

Json response:

```
{
  "took": 178,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 0,
    "successful": 0,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 10000,
      "relation": "gte"
    },
    "max_score": 12.9226,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "17320",
        "_score": 12.9226,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc",
          "State": "CA",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Resident Licensed Sterile Compounding",
              "LicenseNumber": "99658",
              "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91304",
              "City": "Canoga Park"
            },
            {
              "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "50511",
              "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91304",
              "City": "Canoga Park"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "7723",
        "_score": 10.891928,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "ENCINO PHARMACY_AKA MDR PHARMACEUTICAL CARE",
          "State": "MI",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "PHARMACY",
              "LicenseNumber": "5301010993",
              "AddressLine1": "17071 VENTURA BLVD STE 100",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91316",
              "City": "ENCINO"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "7724",
        "_score": 9.796367,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "Encino Pharmacy_aka Mdr Pharmaceutical Care",
          "State": "CA",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "34818",
              "AddressLine1": "17059-17071 VENTURA BLVD.",
              "AddressLine2": "STE. 100",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "91316",
              "City": "ENCINO"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "192",
        "_score": 9.656487,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "Abdin Pharmacies Pharma LLC",
          "State": "FL",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "036936",
              "AddressLine1": "1873 SECOND AVE. NEW",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "10029",
              "City": "YORK"
            },
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "033404",
              "AddressLine1": "1401 BRONX RIVER AVE.",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "10472",
              "City": "BRONX"
            },
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "PH33043",
              "AddressLine1": "32866 US Hwy 19N",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "34684",
              "City": "PALM HARBOR"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "pulse",
        "_id": "17304",
        "_score": 9.186218,
        "_source": {
          "ProfileName": "PHARMALABS, LLC PharmaLabs",
          "State": "FL",
          "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
          "LicenseInfo": [
            {
              "LicenseType": "Pharmacy",
              "LicenseNumber": "PH26495",
              "AddressLine1": "10901 ROOSEVELT BOULEVARD NORTH SUITE 1200",
              "AddressLine2": "",
              "AddressLine3": "",
              "AddressLine4": "",
              "Zip": "33716",
              "City": "Saint Petersburg"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

in UI, i need to display,
Profile Name as name in UI, along with multiple address present under same ProfileName, for example one sample i have taken from json, so from this array of object must contain,

```
[{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'21441 Osborne St Ste C & D,Canoga Park CA 9104'},
{name:'Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc', address:'21442 Osborne St Ste C & D(Address2/Address3/Address4)what ever is present must show, Canoga Park CA 9104'}]
```

so it is like with one Profile Name, we have multiple location address

```
 "_source": {
      "ProfileName": "Pharmarx Pharmaceutical Inc",
      "State": "CA",
      "BusinessModel": "Dispenser",
      "LicenseInfo": [
        {
          "LicenseType": "Resident Licensed Sterile Compounding",
          "LicenseNumber": "99658",
          "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
          "AddressLine2": "",
          "AddressLine3": "",
          "AddressLine4": "",
          "Zip": "91304",
          "City": "Canoga Park"
        },
        {
          "LicenseType": "Retail Pharmacy",
          "LicenseNumber": "50511",
          "AddressLine1": "21441 Osborne St Ste C & D",
          "AddressLine2": "",
          "AddressLine3": "",
          "AddressLine4": "",
          "Zip": "91304",
          "City": "Canoga Park"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some issues in your code, but the main reason that you get the previous result is that you do:

```
if (this.resultData) {
  return this.resultData;
}
```

If `this.resultData` is populated with the data from a previous request it will return immediately before the observable (`this.searchService.searchOpenSearchData(serchVal)`) emits and sets a new value for `this.resultData`.

You should set `this.resultData` to the result of the observable from the api request and await the result rather then returning it like you did in your code.

Something like:

```
private getAutoPopulateData(serchVal: any): Observable<string[]> {
  let data: any = [];
  let results: any = [];
  if (serchVal && serchVal.length > 0) {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.resultData = this.searchService.searchOpenSearchData(serchVal).pipe(
      map((searchData: AutoPopulate) => {
        results = searchData.hits;
        if (results.hits.length > 0) {
          results.hits.forEach(h => {
            let item=h._source;
            let addressProps=Object.keys(item).filter(
              p => p.startsWith('AddressLine') && item[p].length > 0
            );
            addressProps.forEach(ap => {
              let addresses=item[ap].map((ai,idx)=>{
              let address= `${ai} ${item.City[idx]} ${item.State} ${item.Zip[idx]}`;
              return {name:item.ProfileName, address}
            });
            data = data.concat(addresses);
            this.seeResultsData = data.length;
          });
          return data;
        }
        return null;
      }),
      finalize(() => this.isLoading = false);
    );
  } else {
    this.resultData = of(null);
  }
  return this.resultData;
}
```

I tried to return `null` where needed, but check if those places are according to your need+s (maybe you want to return an empty array instead). I used `pipe`, `map` and `finalize` from rxjs which need to be imported. I moved your `isLoading = false` into finalize so it also "stops loading" on error responses.

If further questions, leave a comment.

### UPDATE

After you added additional code to your question in an "edit" I have to update my answer:

With the changes I mention above, your `autoCompleteFormInit` method should change as follows:

```
private this.subscription: Subscription;

private autoCompleteFormInit() {
  this.subscription = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges.pipe(
    debounceTime(500),
    switchMap(value => this.getAutoPopulateData(value))
  ).subscribe(value => this.filteredOptions = value);
}

// To prevent memory leaks, store subscription and unsubscribe on destroy
public ngOnDestroy(): void {
  if (this.subscription) this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

I also changed the logic regarding `isLoading`, it is better if it is only called in the method that actually sends the request.

There is still a lot more that can be improved, but this should work with minimal code changes in the original posted code example.

Comment: with the above code, it is not hitting api and i am not able to see error also in console

Comment: @Bhrungarajni You need to subscribe to the observable where you call `getAutoPopulateData` outside of this code. If you don't subscribe anywhere it won't execute the observable.

Comment: yes i have subscribed in autoComplete method

Comment: @Bhrungarajni This code with the autoComplete method was added to the question after I answered. When you ask a question you should make sure that all relevant parts of the code are added. I will see later if I can update my answer...

Comment: ya please Wilt, today i have added json data based on answer from Daniel

Comment: thanks for response Wilt, so i need to add both methods from your code right?

Comment: api is hitting but not able to see data in html, i mean under dropdown value is not showing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253255/discussion-between-bhrungarajni-and-wilt).

Comment: hi @Wilt, can you please check this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76217665/how-to-show-parent-child-relation-using-treedata-in-angular15-using-ag-grid