# how to show parent child relation using treedata in angular15 using ag-grid

Tags: javascript, json, angular, binary-tree, ag-grid-angular

i am using angular15 ag-grid, here i need to show UI as parent child relation, and i have data as shown in demo.
so here, linking is that -

- ParentId is null means it is Parent,
- id must match with parentId, so here id is 1 for John Smith and "parentId": "1" for Jane Smith, so John Smith is parent of Jane Smith same way  "id": "2", for Jane Smith and Mary Smith and Bob Smith is having ParentId as 2, so they are children of Jane smith and grand children of John smith

Json Data:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "John Smith",
    "age": 30,
    "address": "123 Main St.",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "parentId": null
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Jane Smith",
    "age": 25,
    "address": "456 Oak St.",
    "email": "jane@example.com",
    "parentId": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Mary Smith",
    "age": 3,
    "address": "456 Oak St.",
    "email": "mary@example.com",
    "parentId": "2"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Bob Smith",
    "age": 1,
    "address": "456 Oak St.",
    "email": "bob@example.com",
    "parentId": "2"
  }
]
```

so here, the hierarchy goes in this flow:
John Smith is 1st Parent

- Jane Smith child
  -- Mary Smith and Bob Smith are grand children
  so by default - John Smith will be shown, on click of arrow Jane Smith will be shown, on click of arrow Mary and Bob Smith to be shown along with address.

HTml:

```
<ag-grid-angular style="width: 100%; height: 80%;" class="ag-theme-alpine" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
[defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [autoGroupColumnDef]="autoGroupColumnDef" [rowData]="rowData"
[rowSelection]="rowSelection" [treeData]="true" [animateRows]="true" [getDataPath]="getDataPath"
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [headerHeight]="0" (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged($event)"></ag-grid-angular>
```

Ts:

```
 public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    { field: 'address', minWidth: 400 },
    { field: 'businessModels', minWidth: 300 },
    { field: 'accessLevelStatus', minWidth: 100 },
  ];

  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
  };
  public autoGroupColumnDef = (ColDef = {
    headerName: 'Organisation Hierarchy',
    minWidth: 300,
    cellStyle: function (params) {
      return { color: '#922269' };
    },
    cellRendererParams: {
      checkbox: false,
      suppressCount: true,
    },
  });

  public rowData = [
    {
      id: '1',
      name: 'John Smith',
      age: 30,
      address: '123 Main St.',
      email: 'john@example.com',
      parentId: null,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      name: 'Jane Smith',
      age: 25,
      address: '456 Oak St.',
      email: 'jane@example.com',
      parentId: '1',
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      name: 'Mary Smith',
      age: 3,
      address: '789 Oak St.',
      email: 'mary@example.com',
      parentId: '2',
    },
    {
      id: '4',
      name: 'Bob Smith',
      age: 1,
      address: '122 Oak St.',
      email: 'bob@example.com',
      parentId: '2',
    },
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.rowSelection = 'multiple';
  }
  
  onCellClicked(params) {
    params.node.setSelected(true, true);
  }


}
```

Expected Json:

```
[
 {
       "orgHierarchy": [
          "John Smith"
       ],
       "address": "123 main St.",
       "businessModels": "Dispenser,Distributor",
       "accessLevelStatus": "Owner"
    },
    {
       "orgHierarchy": [
          "John Smith",
          "Jane Smith"
       ],
       "address": "456 Oak St.",
       "businessModels": "Dispenser,Distributor",
       "accessLevelStatus":"Owner"
    },
     {
        "orgHierarchy": [
           "John Smith",
           "Jane Smith",
           "Mary Smith"
        ],
        "address": "456 Oak St.",
        "businessModels": "Dispenser,Distributor",
        "accessLevelStatus": "Owner"
     },
    {
       "orgHierarchy": [
          "John Smith",
          "Jane Smith",
          "Bob Smith"
       ],
       "address": "456 Oak St.",
       "businessModels": "Dispenser,Distributor",
       "accessLevelStatus": "Owner"
    },
]
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-tree-data-ux4g2c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)